# If the Server responds in text/html type, will the Client not recognize it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried to erase jwt token using localStorage.removeItem() function, but failed as a result of running the code below.

I'm coding using Javascript and Express.js in Visual Studio Code.
And use the Chrome browser.

[Client]

```
secession = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/secession', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'accessToken': JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('tokenValue')),
    }
  })
  .then((result) => {
    return result.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    if (data === 'success secession') {
      localStorage.removeItem('tokenValue');
      alert('Success');
    } else {
      alert('Fail. Try again');
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => err);
}
```

[Server]

```
secession: async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = req.get('accessToken');
    if (typeof token !== 'undefined') {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(JSON.parse(token), secretKey);
      const result = await users.users.secession(decoded);
      // result is 'success secession' 
      res.send(result);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
}
```

When I change **res.send(result)** to **res.json(result)** on the Server, I succeeded in erasing the token.

I think the Client doesn't receive the response if Server send *result* by text/html.

But I'm not sure this is right.

Comment: Have you tried to add some outputs to browsers console? My shot into the dark: The execution of `stringify()` fails and you don't catch the case if the format of response is not json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending something that is not JSON to the client. With this line:

```
return result.json();
```

You are telling the browser to parse it as JSON. Which it isn't. An exception will be thrown, however, with this line:

```
.catch((err) => err);
```

you're swallowing up all errors. It's being thrown for a reason: You're feeding the `.json` function invalid input.

Remove the `.json` parser. You could replace it with [`.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text).

### Background information:

The reason why using `res.json()` 'fixes' the issue is because running `JSON.stringify` on `some "string" value` will result in `"some \"string\" value"`, which is valid JSON. A JSON object may be just a string, it needn't be an object or array.